# How to dynamically create a <f:selectItem> list?

Tags: jsf, icefaces

Is there a way to dynamically create a selectItem list? I dont really want to have to create lots of bean code to make my lists return `List<SelectItem>`.

I tried this:

```xml
<ice:selectManyCheckbox>
    <ui:repeat var="product" value="#{productListingService.list}">
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{product.description}" value="#{product.id}"/>
    </ui:repeat>
</ice:selectManyCheckbox>
```

but it doesnt work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use `<f:selectItems>` instead. It accepts next to `List<SelectItem>` and `SelectItem[]` also a `Map<String, Object>` as value where the map key is the item label and map value is the item value. Or if you're already on JSF 2.0, then you can use a `List<SomeBean>` instead where the current item can be referenced by the `var` attribute.

```html
<f:selectItems value="#{productListingService.list}" var="product" 
    itemLabel="#{product.description}" itemValue="#{product.id}" />
```

#### See also:

- [Our `<h:selectOneMenu>` wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info)